# Where Column1 or Column2 equals value

Tags: mysql

I'm just curious if i'm doing this code right--it appears to work on my test server but I'm hesitent to put it live until I know i'm using the OR statement properly.

```
    SELECT privatemessages.threadID, privatemessages.messageID, privatemessages.message_body, privatemessages.uid
FROM privatemessages, privatethreads
WHERE privatemessages.threadID =1
AND privatethreads.threadID = privatemessages.threadID
AND privatethreads.to_user
OR privatethreads.from_user =1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step should be to add parenthesis:

```
SELECT privatemessages.threadID, privatemessages.messageID, privatemessages.message_body, privatemessages.uid
FROM privatemessages, privatethreads
WHERE privatemessages.threadID =1
AND privatethreads.threadID = privatemessages.threadID
AND (privatethreads.to_user
OR privatethreads.from_user =1)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

you will likely always want to use parenthesis, if you mix `and` and `or`.

The comma join syntax is also some kind of "dirty", maybe you want to write your query the following way instead to make more clear what part is join and what part is constraint:

```
SELECT privatemessages.threadID, privatemessages.messageID, privatemessages.message_body, privatemessages.uid
FROM privatemessages
INNER JOIN privatethreads
  ON privatethreads.threadID = privatemessages.threadID
WHERE privatemessages.threadID =1
AND (privatethreads.to_user
OR privatethreads.from_user =1)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Besides the comma join being dirty, are there any reasons why I should favor the other method over it?

Comment: None, which I know of.

Comment: Alright, thank you for answering that. Seeing as every other post below this is telling me to use INNER JOIN (which I personally don't like to use, as the comma join method works just as well)

Comment: Yes, you are only joining two tables. It hardly makes any difference then. There are queries which join like 6 or 10 tables. In those cases the explicit syntax is much easier to read. Also comma syntax is always a `full outer` or `inner` join, but there also exists e.g. `left join`, which can only be used by explicit join syntax. To sum it up, there exist some soft reasons for the explicit join syntax and against the comma syntax, but I do not know of any hard reasons.

Answer (score 0):

No. You're not. And don't use implicit join syntax...

```
SELECT m.threadID
     , m.messageID
     , m.message_body
     , m.uid
  FROM privatemessages m
  JOIN privatethreads t
    ON t.threadID = m.threadID
 WHERE m.threadID = 1
   AND 1 IN (t.to_user,t.from_user)
 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can do either of the following:

```
SELECT 
    privatemessages.threadID, 
    privatemessages.messageID, 
    privatemessages.message_body, 
    privatemessages.uid
FROM privatemessages, privatethreads
WHERE privatemessages.threadID =1
AND privatethreads.threadID = privatemessages.threadID
AND (privatethreads.to_user=1 OR privatethreads.from_user =1)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

OR

```
SELECT 
    privatemessages.threadID, 
    privatemessages.messageID, 
    privatemessages.message_body, 
    privatemessages.uid
FROM privatemessages, privatethreads
WHERE privatemessages.threadID =1
AND privatethreads.threadID = privatemessages.threadID
AND 1 IN (privatethreads.to_user, privatethreads.from_user)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```